# From [0.2, 0.2, 0.2] to "R 0.2 3"

Tags: r, string, parsing, vector

I have a long vector in R in which successive value often repeat themselves. For example

```
x = c(rep(0.2, 1500), rep(0.1, 10007), 0.7, 0.9, rep(0.1, 9784))
```

I am trying to write a function that takes this vector as input and return either of the two following strings

```
s = "R 0.2 1500 R 0.1 10007 R 0.7 1 R 0.9 1 R 0.1 9784"
```

or preferentially

```
s = "R 0.2 1500 R 0.1 10007 0.7 0.9 R 0.1 9784"
```

, where `R 0.7 1 R 0.9 1` became `0.7 0.9`.

For your intuition, `R` stands for `repeat` or `rep`. The string therefore closely ressemble the way I constructed the vector `x` to start with.

I tried looping through each value but that was too slow for my needs. Can you help me out finding a fast solution?

Comment: Have you looked at `rle`?

Comment: `rle` is indeed the way to go. One can make an answer out of any of the 3 answers suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Data
x = c(rep(0.2, 1500), rep(0.1, 10007), 0.7, 0.9, rep(0.1, 9784))

#Run rle and paste values and lengths together
y = paste("R", rle(x)$values, rle(x)$lengths)

#There may be an easier way to do this using regex
#But here is one solution using strsplit
#Remove 1 and R
y = sapply(strsplit(y," "), function(a)
    if (gsub(" ","",a[3]) == "1"){
        a = a[2]
    } else {
    a = a
    }
)

#Collapse everything together
paste(unlist(y), collapse = " ")
#[1] "R 0.2 1500 R 0.1 10007 0.7 0.9 R 0.1 9784"
```